# Eclipse neon extra space for minimize/restore editor buttons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

After upgrading my eclipse to neon from juno, I noticed that I am getting extra space for the min/restore buttons for the c/c++ editor.

looked like this in juno
[image: Juno]

looks like this in neon
[image: Neon]

it doesnt look like much in the screenshots but it adds a tabs heights to the whole window. Anyway to get rid of it, or make it smaller like in Juno ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how to get rid of the extra space, but the space only occurs when you have multiple editors/views side-by-side in the same tab space. That looks like this:

[image]

If you drag the windows such that they are not in the same tab space, then you don't have the extra space:

[image]

Comment: When you drag a tab to one side of the tab group so that it creates a new tab view, the first situation occur. Instead drag the tab to another tab group; it will separate the tab from the tab group and then drag the "isolated tab" anywhere you want, it will stay in its own group.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following style in the .css file that is active for you. For example, add the following to e4-dark.css for eclipse oxygen's dark style.

```
#org-eclipse-ui-editorss {
    swt-tab-height: 5px;
    padding: 0px 2px 2px;
}
```